# Is it possible to loop in SVG?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I wish to create an array of entries from where values of the parameters could be accessed in the following code:

path d=" M 300 250 A 10 15 0 1 0 250 250" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />.

So that I can loop over and  generate the path for different parameters. Is there a way to do it(the looping over the array) ?

```
 !DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   <title>Spline Editor</title>
   <svg width="500" height="500">
   <path d=" M 300 250 A 10 15 0 1 0 250 250"
            stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
            <path d=" M 300 250 A 10 45 0 1 0 250 250"
            stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
            <path d=" M 350 250 A 40 75 0 1 0 250 250"
            stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />

    svg>
```

I wish to do this using a loop.And not having to writing the path statement again and again.

Comment: Question is unclear. Please provide more information on what you are trying to achieve. Is it about the paths `d` attribute or the while set of attributes the path can have?

Comment: I have an array of values of say the minor axes of ellipses. So how can i automatically generate ellipses for all the values of the array without explicitly writing the code each time i.e can i use a for...loop or something like that here.

Answer (score 0):

Just have your array with all the attributes and use d3 data binding:

```
var arr = [
    {d: 'M 300 250 A 10 15 0 1 0 250 250', stroke: 'green', 'strokewidth': 2, fill: 'none'},
    // etc..
];

svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(arr)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) {return d.d;})
    .attr('stroke', function(d) {return d.stroke;})
    .attr('stroke-width', function(d) {return d.strokewidth;})
    .attr('fill', function(d) {return d.fill;});
```

Comment: Thanks but the data I have is in the form of multiple arrays.        var xCoord = [300, 300, 350];
  var yCoord = [250, 250, 250];
  var height=[10 , 20 , 40]; Each array contains just one component to be inserted into the path function. Now How do i combine these values together?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with JavaScript isn't too hard. Take a look at one approach to doing it declaratively:
http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/SVGOpen2010/replicate.htm
In script, just retrieve the path using SVG DOM and reset its d attribute using pathname.setAttribute("d", newdata). Is that the sort of thing you had in mind?